# Android List with section headers

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a list with headers above a grouping of items.  I was looking at SeperatedListAdapter available here: http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/ but I ran into an error `(ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2025):`

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
)
```

Now I'm looking into more options including making a new one.  Do you guys have any hints?

Thanks,
Bryon

Answer (score 12, accepted):

AFAIK, Mr. Sharkey's code works just fine. You may be using the wrong `ArrayAdapter` constructor.

You can also use my [`MergeAdapter`](http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge) to achieve the same ends.

Comment: Yes, shortly after posting I got it to work with a new application, I must have had some sort of conflict.  The linked resource is very helpful, thank you for that.

Comment: Would you recommend Mr. Sharkey's code or are there maybe more robust / performant / native / easier possibilities? He made that list in 2008 with API 0.9, maybe there are better options now?

Comment: @OneWorld: The only real issue with Mr. Sharkey's code is the GPL license, if that would be an issue for you. The performance of his adapter or my adapter are similar, though the performance issues would tend to lie elsewhere (e.g., in your getting the stuff together in a form that works either adapter). And, both are meant to demonstrate general techniques that could be applied to a custom adapter of your own devising.

Comment: The sample project link that @CommonsWare gave points to his `Sections` project, which actually uses a GPL derivative of Mr Sharkey's code. The `MergeAdapter` [demo](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge/tree/master/demo) is found inside the `[MergeAdapter](http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge)` project

Answer (score 4):

That's how I solved the sectioning in ListViews with an ArrayAdapter
http://bartinger.at/listview-with-sectionsseparators/

Answer (score 2):

We have this same problem and have found the following two projects that meet our needs:

- [StickyListHeaders](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders)
- [StickyGridHeaders](https://github.com/TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders)